# How do I extract only bold text from this image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am looking for an approach / algorithm for using OCR (like Tesseract) to extract only bold text from an image. The Python code I wrote can already identify small letters and numbers, but it cannot distinguish between bold and non-bold text.

Does someone have an idea, for example, for some preprocessing or postprocessing of the image to make this work? I am not looking for coding or implementation help, only for an algorithmic idea. As another tool, I could use OpenCV.

For illustration purposes, this is my current code:

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

if __name__ == '__main__':

  if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: test.py image.jpg')
    sys.exit(1)

  # Read image path from command line
  imPath = sys.argv[1]


  # Define config parameters.
  # '-l eng'  for using the English language
  # '--oem 1' for using LSTM OCR Engine
  config = ('-l sin --oem 1 --psm 3')

  # Read image from disk

  im = cv2.imread(imPath, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

  #im = cv2.imread(imPath)
  #im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)




  # Run tesseract OCR on image
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config=config)
file = open("testfile.txt","w") 
file.write(text)
file.close()
#Print recognized text
#print(text)
```

Comment: I took the freedom to edit this question into a conceptional one. So everyone, please think twice before you hit the downvote / close vote buttons now (at least please leave a comment why you think the question should be closed even now).

Answer (score 6):

[image: It can be hard to explain the difference between the easy and the virtually impossible]

Your problem falls into the 'needs five years and a research team' bucket!

As far as I know tesseract doesn't have an option for this; you are just using a library not designing the algorithms!

You might be able to hack something together combining .image_to_boxes() and .image_to_data() and some sort of custom .box_is_bold() method that you would have to design and develop. You might be able to create a heuristic to decide between bold and non-bold text in a region. N.b. developing a robust heuristic is non-trivial.

Edit: I may have been wrong, .image_to_data() may contain information relating to boldface characteristics.

Comment: Am I missing something? According to (very old) stackoverflow questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163329, Tesseract 3.0.1 supports extracting character attributas, including boldface. Did this capability go away?

Comment: @KilianFoth well i can be wrong, I didn't see anything in the quick look i took, but if it does support that, then .image_to_data() will work by it self.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given an example image. so this is speculation.

One simple method you could do is to [*erode*](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/erode.htm) the image.
This should result in the non-bold text being removed, leaving only the bold text (now thinner) to be passed through to the OCR stage.

From above link (because who doesn't like images):
[image: Example of erosion on pixels]

Comment: I had thought of this, but i thought algorithm always leaves something behind, i.e. if you erroded the output again it should pass un-changed. I may have been wrong.

Comment: if you erode the original image again, then yes, you will get the same output.  If you were to run the erosion on the output from above though, every pixel in the output would be black.

Comment: `scikit-image` has a `remove_small_objects`, although choosing the accurate threshold might be hard, as is choosing the right structuring element for the morphological operations. Furthermore, there is a thinning operation and you could use the ration between thinned and original area of connected components as an estimator of boldness. Finally you could train a CNN on artificially created texts with random bold-faces inserted, which will be the most stable approach regarding hyperparameters.